# Loop MutationObserver for addedNodes won't run properly + JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <section class="main-content">
    </section>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        console.log(mutations);
        $.each(mutations, function(k, v) {
            $.each(v.addedNodes, function(k2, v2) {
                $('div.alert', v2[0]).each(function() {
                    $alert = $(this);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $alert.fadeOut(1000);
                    }, 2000);
                });
            });
        })
    });
    observer.observe(document, {attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree:true});
    $('section.main-content').prepend(
      createAlert({
        type: 'success',
        content: 'success'
      })
    ).prepend(
      createAlert({
        type: 'warning',
        content: 'warning'
      })
    );
});

function createAlert(alert) {
    var alert_default = {
        type: 'primary',
        content: 'Content'
    }
    var alert = $.extend(alert_default, alert);
    return (
        '<div class="alert alert-' + alert.type + ' alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">' +
                '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>' +
            '</button>' +
            alert.content +
        '</div>'
    );
}
```

The code shoudld fadeOut all inserted `<div class"alert">` even if they are inserted at the same time. but it just doesn't work properly, only the last div.alert that fadeOut.

Here is the https://jsfiddle.net/u58xezqv/

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the jQuery object to `setTimeout()` for `$alert` to reference the same element, also inner nested `$.each()` is not necessary

```
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    console.log(mutations);
    $.each(mutations, function(k, v) {
      console.log(v);
      $.each(v.addedNodes, function(k2, v2) {
        var $alert = $(v2);
        setTimeout(function(el) {
          el.fadeOut(1000);
        }, 2000, $alert);
      });
    })
  });
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u58xezqv/3/

Comment: @BrianAntiqueña Note, the actual issue was using global `$alert` instead of `var $alert` https://jsfiddle.net/u58xezqv/4/

Comment: your first answer works fine without var in jsfiddle.? I've also tried delay instead of settimeout and it works now. thanks